# LinkButton control lifecycle, when do I declare the button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, lifecycle

If I have a LinkButton in an ItemTemplate of a GridView, and I want that LinkButton to fire it's events (having given up on the row event), when should I declare the button?

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" OnInit="EditLinkButton_Init" CommandName="Edit" OnCommand="EditLinkButton_Command" ID="EditLinkButton"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The only event below that ever fires is EditLinkButton_Init. The text of the LinkButton is changed to ROCKON, so I think the events should fire as well? I'm still LifeCycle challenged, so if you could offer a brief explanation or link that would be great.

Here is the code-behind:

```
    protected void EditLinkButton_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton myLinkButton = new LinkButton();
        myLinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
        myLinkButton.Text = "ROCKON";
        myLinkButton.Click += new EventHandler(EditLinkButton_Click);
        myLinkButton.CommandName = "Edit";
        myLinkButton.Command += myLinkButton_Command;
    }

    void myLinkButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected void EditLinkButton_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void EditLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I've desperately thrown everything I can think of at it....

Comment: in `EditLinkButton_Init` method you just create new link button and doesnt add it to gridview. if you want to refer to the `LinkButton` you should use `LinkButton myLinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;` instead of `LinkButton myLinkButton = new LinkButton();`

Comment: You are correct of course, thank you! However, after fixing that I still cannot get an event to fire. I should mention that the GridView is in a Content placeholder of a Master page, if that matters?

Comment: I stupidly re-generated the page from Site Master, wiping out the ViewState. After I corrected that the page behaved as expected.